# screen manager with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation

Tags: fedora, process, gnu-screen

If I join with 'screen' to existing sessions, I can get a list of the sessions with C-a " keystroke and switch between them, however I can't find a way to safely leave/detach and keep all the processes running; if I press C-a \ it seems that it kills the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `\` at all? The detach character is `d`.

Comment: Right, C-A d just detaches and exits. Thanks!